# Fpdf automatic AddPage()

Tags: php, fpdf

I want to create automatic a new page if there is content longer than my pdf in fpdf. The content is in every pdf file different to each other.
If I add AddPage() manually sometimes its to late and sometimes to early because of the different content every time.

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: You need to keep track of the current Y position on the page, how much text you have left to write, and the height of each page. If you have more to write than the amount of space left on the page, then add a new page.

Comment: @bassxzero that sounds good. Is there already any code on the internet for this?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=fpdf&oq=fpdf